# How do I get the Unix timestamp?

Tags: 8, datetime

I want to use `format_date()`, but it requires a Unix timestamp and my dates are ISO.

Is there a drupal way to convert ISO date to Unix timestamp? If I use strtotime, I lose my timezone offset.

Answer (score 10):

You shouldn't use `format_date()` anymore.  You should create a `DrupalDateTime` object, and then use the `format()` method.

```
$date = \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime::createFromFormat('c', $my_iso_8601_date);
$my_rfc2822_string = $date->format('r');
```

Comment: I can't get it to work. This is what I'm passing: 2016-06-07T14:00:00, and I'd like to get this in return (except have it go through any timezone conversions): 1465308000

Comment: @Greg Per spec, ISO 8601 dates have to include the time zone portion, so that doesn't comply with that format.  Try either adding the timezone to what you are passing in, or use the PHP date format placeholders to build up a format string that matches what you are passing in. `DrupalDateTime::createFromFormat` works; it's how the field storage parses data from the database, but you do have to make sure your format string works (it's also wrapper to \DateTime::createFromFormat, but takes into account Drupal TZ handling).

Comment: Thank you MPD, I went with a straight PHP solution for the time being.  I will look into the DrupalDateTime in the future though.

Comment: @Greg My bad, 'c' is not an accepted format for http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php; it will work if you build the format string from the parts listed there.

Comment: @mpdonadio, can you edit your answer with the updated comment ? Iso8601 should be Y-m-d\TH:i:sT (even though I still haven't got it to work)

Answer (score 4):

`format_date` deprecated in Drupal 8.0.0, will be removed before Drupal 9.0.0.

It's better to do it with Drupal way, using Drupal time service:

```
$time_value = \Drupal::time()->getCurrentTime();
print \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format($time_value, 'long');
```

Comment: Here are the available built in format other than 'long': https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21DateFormatter.php/function/DateFormatter%3A%3Aformat/8.2.x

Answer (score 3):

> I can't get it to work. This is what I'm passing: 2016-06-07T14:00:00,
>   and I'd like to get this in return (except have it go through any
>   timezone conversions): 1465308000

It's simple - you can use standard getTimestamp() function within the DrupalDateTime object:

```
$date = '2016-06-07T14:00:00';
$dateTime = new DrupalDateTime($date, 'UTC');
$timestamp = $dateTime->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: This should be the right answer, thx!!

Answer (score 3):

In Drupal 9 you can get the current timestamp using the following

```
use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;
$current_timestamp = (new DrupalDateTime())->getTimestamp();
```

DrupalDateTime is a wrapper over PHP DateTime object.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up using.  I would like to experiment with MPD's solution more and will up date this question if I do.

```
$start_date = new DateTime($my_IOS_date, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$start_date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

$my_timestamp = $start_date->getTimestamp();
```